# Laravel Twig - Accesing Sentry check function and user fields

Tags: laravel, twig, cartalyst-sentry

I'm trying to check if Sentry user is logged in on twig template on a Laravel project, i'm using `twigbridge`.

How do i?

```
{% if Sentry::Check() == false %}
```

This gives me:

> Unexpected token "punctuation" of value ":" ("end of statement block" expected) in "layouts.menu" at line 61

Same for:

```
{{ Sentry::getUser()->first_name }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
Sentry
```

in config of twigbridge under fascades key.

In twig template use

```
{{ Sentry.getUser().first_name }}
```

You may have to run command

```
composer dump-autoload
```